# SQL Statement that should order by Last Column then First Column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I want to sort my entries in alphabetical order based on two fields First and Last.

Both fields have the domain of `CHAR(30)`. Neither of the fields is a key of any kind.

For an example I am using the following table.

```
Last        First
Banner      Bruce
Wayne       Bruce
Wayne       Benjamin
Kent        Clark
Rodgers     Steve
Jordan      Hal
Stark       Tony
Howlett     Logan
```

I then use the following SQL Statement which according to [here](http://www.sqlcommands.net/sql+order+by/) (Look at the last example) Is a valid SQL Statement that should sort by Last name then a sub-sort of the First names.

```
SELECT * FROM Heros ORDER BY Last ASC, First ASC;
```

The results I am looking for are:

```
Last        First
Banner      Bruce
Howlett     Logan
Jordan      Hal
Kent        Clark
Rodgers     Steve
Stark       Tony
Wayne       Benjamin
Wayne       Bruce
```

Instead I get:

```
Last        First
Banner      Bruce
Howlett     Logan
Jordan      Hal
Kent        Clark
Rodgers     Steve
Stark       Tony
Wayne       Bruce
Wayne       Benjamin
```

Basically the last two rows are not sorted by First name after they were sorted by their Last name. I am not sure what is why the rows returned are not ordered as I had expected. Besides SQlCommands.net I looked at dev.mysql.com. Several Stack Overflow topics had suggested answers where the SQL Statement was almost identical to this syntax. Any thoughts on what I am missing would be very appreciated.

Comment: can you try SELECT * FROM Heros ORDER BY lower(last),lower(first);

Comment: I think that your query is correct.
Are you sure that the last name values for the two last rows are identical?  Perhaps one of the them has some trailing white space that's throwing off last name sort.

Comment: It gives me [the expected result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5e79/1)

Comment: Is there a non printable character after "Wayne" (Benjamin)? How many rows does `select * from Heros where Last = "Wayne";` returns?

Comment: Can you check the records in last 2 rows, if it contains space before or after the field, check both first  and last fields.

Comment: Its always the little things. I dumped all the records in that table and reloaded them and it works...must have been that extra space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there are space around First or Last name then try [`Trim()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function in `ORDER BY` clause like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Heros 
ORDER BY TRIM(Last) ASC
       , TRIM(First) ASC;
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c0a9c/3)